# Splittings in the difference bundle construction of Atiyah-Hirzebruch

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, intersection-theory

I'm reading the construction of difference bundle(generalized) in the paper of Atiyah-Hirzebruch(Analytic cycles on complex manifolds)

There is one thing I cannot understand. The followings are in the page 34 in the paper.

For exact sequence of vector bundles on $Y$.

$0 \to E_n \stackrel{a_n}{\to} E_{n-1} \to \dots \to E_1 \stackrel{a_1}{\to} E_0 \stackrel{a_0}{\to} 0$

Let $F_i := Ker(a_i)$. Then $F_i$ are vector bundles and the following short exact sequences

$0 \to F_i \to E_i \to F_{i-1} \to 0$ splits.

I cannot find the reason why they splits and there is no condition on the space $Y$. Is there a reason the above sequence splits, or the term 'split' used in a different sense?

Comment: If your base space is paracompact then it is possible to equip $E_i$ with a metric. Consider the decomposition of $E_i$ into $F_i$ and its orthogonal complement which is isomorphic to $F_{i-1}$. Now it is possible to construct a splitting map.

Comment: I forgot to write something. In this case, $E_i$'s are complex vector bundles. Is it possible to induce complex structure to the orthogonal complement of $E_i$?

It looks little strange for me because then, if the base space is paracompact, then every short exact sequence splits!. In general, it never happens in algebraic geometry. What is a difference when there is a metric?

Comment: It is true that every short exact sequence of complex vector bundles split, by the above argument. However, it is not true that every short exact sequence of _holomorphic_ vector bundles split, as in algebraic geometry.

Comment: I think I understood what I missed. I appreciate for all comments :)